docker-compose no funciona con nextjs14 + golang
Tengo la siguiente estructura de carpeta:
/backend (en golang)
/frontend (en next14)
compose.yml
Dentro de backend/ tengo su despectivo Dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.22

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY main.go .

RUN go get
RUN go build -o bin .

EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/bin"]


Dentro de frontend/ el Dockerfile es el siguiente:
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]


En compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: front-paperworksmanager
    image: front-paperworksmanager:1.0.0
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - paper
  backend:
    container_name: back-paperworksmanager
    image: back-paperworksmanager:1.0.0
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - paper

networks:
  paper:
    external: true

Hice muchos intentos por lo cual en comopose.yml opte por crear manualmente
la network "paper"
Al momento de ejecutar docker compose up El backend se genera pero next me arroja el error :
9.652 TypeError: fetch failed
9.652     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12500:13
9.652     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
9.652     at async globalThis.fetch (/app/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:36484)
9.652     at async n (/app/.next/server/app/hello/page.js:1:2484)
9.652     at async a (/app/.next/server/app/hello/page.js:1:2560) {
9.652   [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000
9.652       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16)
9.652       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
9.652     errno: -111,
9.652     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
9.652     syscall: 'connect',
9.652     address: '127.0.0.1',
9.652     port: 4000
9.652   }
9.652 }

Por el lado de nextjs estoy haciendo una peticion server side:
src/app/hello/page.tsx
const greetings = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/hello");
  return response.text();
};

export default async function hola() {
  const x = await greetings();
  return (
    <>
      <p>{x}</p>
    </>
  );
}

Ya intente poniendo en el fetch : http://backend:4000/hello pero no funciono.

si necesitas hacer un request desde tu servicio de front al de back no tenes que usar localhost ya que ambos servicios están en el container de docker (No en el localhost de tu máquina), por lo que tenes que utilizar el nombre del servicio:
http://backend:4000/hello


En el post , en la ultima linea comento que eso no me funciono.Gracias

Perdón no había visto el comentario final. Que error te tira cuando haces el request con http://backend:4000/hello
